# how to mysql random select table name

Tags: mysql

perhaps i'm missing something here. I am trying to randomly select a table name from a database that only has numbers/numeric ONLY. Here's what I've gotten but when test running the query, mysql is telling me that my query is incorrect. Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM `master` WHERE TABLES is NUMERIC ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether you can get the result using show tables.

But, you can definitely use information_schema to achieve the same

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'master' 
AND CAST(TABLE_NAME AS UNSIGNED) <> 0 
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

To Suppress Truncated data warnings, use the following query using regexp

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'master' 
AND TABLE_NAME REGEXP '^(-|\\+)?([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$'
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you - this works great, but I'm getting a bunch of errors for tables that is not numeric `Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'Apple'`